# How to generate database diagrams from the command line in Fedora 19?

Tags: command-line, fedora, yum, mariadb, erd

I'm new to Linux and have just installed Fedora 19 in VirtualBox.

I am running MariaDB and am wanting to generate database diagrams from the command line.

I have come across a few examples of output from [SQLFairy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlfairy/):

http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2009/01/11/easy-visualisation-of-database-schemas-using-sqlfairy/

http://www.christianbiggins.com/2008/11/er-diagrams-from-sql-files.html

http://techmania.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/creating-er-diagrams-from-sql/

And that seems to be the type of thing I am after.

I did a yum search with `'yum search sqlfairy'` but there didn't seem to be any results.

Could anyone please tell me how to install sqlfairy in Fedora 19, or, if that's not possible, recommend a product that does a similar thing?

**Edit:**

I found this: https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/perl-SQL-Translator#f19

and installed via `yum install perl-SQL-Translator`.

I am now trying:

```
[me@my ~]  sqlt-graph -f MySQL -o mydatabase.png -t png mydatabase.sql
```

but am getting error:

```
ERROR (line 36): Invalid statement: Was expecting comment, 
or use, or set, or drop, or create, or alter, or insert, or 
delimiter, or empty statement
Error: translate: Error with parser 'SQL::Translator::Parser::MySQL':  
no results at /usr/bin/sqlt-graph line 195.
```

The .sql  file is located is `home/me` which is where I am running the command from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to follow the steps above, the error was solved by using the following for the mysqldump command, then the sqlt command above worked:

```
[username@hostname ~] mysqldump -u root -pmysql_root_password --no-data database_name > example.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/diagramming.html), which can generate database diagrams from the command line. It works on Linux, and needs Java installed. You will need to find a JDBC driver for MariaDB.

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler

Comment: Is this tool still maintained? The link is now broken.

Comment: @bfontaine - yes, it is - please see https://www.schemacrawler.com/